# Rails: How to implement counter caching with self-referential Many to Many via has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I roll my own counter cache for a self-referential many-to-many relationship that uses `has_many :through`?

I need to track the number of citations and references for each article

I'm using roughly the code from the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536261/tricky-active-record-relationships-polymorphic-bi-directional-self-referential):

```
class Publication < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :citations
  has_many :cited_publications, :through => :citations, :source => :reference
  has_many :references, :foreign_key => "reference_id", :class_name => "Citation"
  has_many :refered_publications, :through => :references, :source => :publication
end

class Citation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :publication
  belongs_to :reference, :class_name => "Publication"
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Rails counter cache mechanism uses the [increment_counter](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002223) and [decrement_counter](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002224) methods internally. You should just be able to invoke those methods from the [standard ActiveRecord callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/activerecord_validations_callbacks.html#creating-an-object).

Something like this should give you the idea:

```
class Citation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :publication
  belongs_to :reference, :class_name => "Publication"

  after_create  :increment_counter_cache
  after_destroy :decrement_counter_cache

  private
  def decrement_counter_cache
    Publication.decrement_counter("citations_counter", publication_id)
  end

  def increment_counter_cache
    Publication.increment_counter("citations_counter", publication_id)
  end
```

end

Comment: Thanks John.  That was about 1/2 of what I needed to know but it got me going.  I actually had to increment and decrement both the publication_id article's count and the reference_id article's count.

Comment: Good, I'm glad it helped. I thought that you'd have to increment both.

Answer (score 3):

For has_many :through AssociationAutomatic, deletion of join models is direct, no destroy callbacks are triggered. So decrement counter will not work in this case