# Rails Eager Loading Question Find(:all, :include => [:model])

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, eager-loading

I have a Topic and a Project model. I have a Many-to-many ass between them (HABTM one).

In the Topic's Index Page, I want to display the number of projects that each topic have. So I have

```
@topics = Topic.all(:include => [:projects])
```

In my controller, and so far so good. The problem is that the Project Model is so big that the query is still really slow

```
Topic Load (1.5ms)   SELECT * FROM "topics" 

Project Load (109.2ms)   SELECT "projects".*, t0.topic_id as the_parent_record_id FROM "projects" INNER JOIN "projects_topics" t0 ON "projects".id = t0.project_id WHERE (t0.topic_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11))
```

Is there a way to make the second query not to select * but just the name or the ID? Because the counter_cache is not supported by the HABTM Ass, and I don't really want to implement it by myself... so is there a way to make this second query faster?

I just need to pull the count without loading the whole project object...

Thanks in advance,

Nicolás Hock Isaza

Answer (score 4):

1. counter_cache is very easy to implement
2. you can convert habtm to double has_many, i.e. has_many :projects_topics in both project and topic model (and belongs_to in projects_topics) and then use counter_cache or do eager loading only on projects_topics
3. you can do :select => "count(projects_topics.id)", :group => "topics.id"  but this won't work well with postgresql if you care about it...

The second option is the best IMO, I usually don't use habtm at all, only double has_many :)

Comment: The 2nd option is the best one.  I'd also make sure you have the right database indexes set on your projects table.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Devenv's answer [counter cache](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) is what you would typically use for this kind of scenario.

From the api docs:

> Caches the number of belonging objects
>   on the associate class through the use
>   of increment_counter and
>   decrement_counter. The counter cache
>   is incremented when an object of this
>   class is created and decremented when
>   it‘s destroyed. This requires that a
>   column named #{table_name}_count (such
>   as comments_count for a belonging
>   Comment class) is used on the
>   associate class (such as a Post
>   class). You can also specify a custom
>   counter cache column by providing a
>   column name instead of a true/false
>   value to this option (e.g.,
>   :counter_cache => :my_custom_counter.)
>   Note: Specifying a counter cache will
>   add it to that model‘s list of
>   readonly attributes using
>   attr_readonly.

[Here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column) is a screen cast from ryan bates' [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/) on counter_cache.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978779/rails-how-to-implement-counter-caching-with-self-referential-many-to-many-via-ha) is an answer to a question I asked half a year ago where the solution was an easily implemented home-brew counter cache.